# php for loop not sent to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having this problem when I have a for loop of links and I want each link to alert through jquery but only the first link is working.. What could be the problem?

```
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='CSS/nook.css' type='text/css' media='screen, projection' />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

This is my script

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#click").click(function(e) 
            {
                e.preventDefault(); 
                alert("hi");
            });
         })
        </script>
```

And this is my loop

```
        <?php
         for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
           echo "<a href = '' id = 'click'>a</a><br>";
         }
         ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID of an element must be unique, use class to group similar elements

```
    <?php
     for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
       echo "<a href = '' class='click'>a</a><br>";
     }
     ?>
```

then

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".click").click(function(e) 
        {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            alert("hi");
        });
     })
    </script>
```

When you use [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), it will return only the first element with the given id others will be ignored. So in your case the click handler will be registered to only the first element withe the id `click`

Comment: is this possible if i submit a form in the jquery?

Comment: @Nhiz you can call `$('form').submit()`

Comment: i seem to get the idea but it isn't working for me. I have two input buttons in my form like this for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
echo "<form class='post_comment'>";
echo "<div><input type='submit'  class='commment' name='comment' value='$i'/></div>";
echo "</form>";
} but whenever i click the button, i can't alert its value

Comment: @Nhiz can you share the generated html

Comment: how will i do that? sorry i don't get it

Comment: @Nhiz from the browser view source get the html part in question... I'm not seeing the link which was posted in the question inside the form...

Comment: i have posted it to another question. please help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842271/data-value-of-input-button-inside-a-form

Answer (score 0):

IDs are unique, and you should only have 1 per page. So this is wrong:

```
<a id="unique"></a>
<a id="unique"></a>
```

Instead, you need to use a class:

```
<a class="not_unique"></a>
<a class="not_unique"></a>
```

The way you access a class with jquery is with `.` instead of `#`:

```
$(".click")
```