# data value of input button inside a form

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I have a  for loop that shows two forms with input button, how will i get the value of the input button?

```
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='CSS/nook.css' type='text/css' media='screen, projection' />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
    $(".post_comment").submit(function(e) 
      {
       e.preventDefault(); 
       var s = $(".comment").data('i');
       alert(s);
    });
   })
   </script>

   <?php

       for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
         echo "<form class='post_comment'>";
         echo "<div><input type='submit'  class='commment'  data-i = '$i' value='$i'/></div>";
         echo "</form>";
        }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the input element which is inside the submitted form

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".post_comment").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var s = $(this).find(".comment").data('i');
        alert(s);
        var value = $(this).find(".comment").val();
        alert(value);
    });
})
```

You also have a spelling mistake in your markup, `class='commment'` should be `class='comment'` - there are 3 `m` in your class name

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/R2hPu/)

Note: Use console logging for debugging instead of `alert()`